# aws s3 upload svg file has wrong content-type

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3, fabricjs

i have to upload my svg file to s3 bucket

when i upload svg file using javascript sdk, file is uploaded in s3 bucket.

but it has wrong content type(not image/xml+svg)

here is my code and please tell me how to upload svg file by correct content-type

```
var svgData = canvas.toSVG();
var svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});        
s3.upload({ Key: svgkey,
            Body:svgData,
            contentType : 'image/svg+xml'
} , function(err , data){

})
```

Comment: What content type do you see?

Comment: Try to rename your parameter to `ContentType`

Comment: Thankyou so much really!!